# Shiny hover - strange date format

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a shiny app with a graph of a timeseries and a hover event which outputs the date and value for the current hovered over value. Strangely it outputs a date format which I can't quite put my finger on. For example `2013-05-03` becomes `1.369267e+12`. Can someone explain this?

Here's a working example:

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    position = "left",

    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("fund", label = NULL, selected = "", choices = c('', LETTERS[1:6]), options = list(placeholder = "Choose something"), width = "350px"),
      verbatimTextOutput("hover")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("tsplot")
    )


  )
))
```

**server.r**

```
require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  PFobj <- reactive({

    pf <- input$fund
    ts_info <- list(a = "x", b = "y")
    ts_data <- data.frame(Dat = seq(Sys.Date() - 200, Sys.Date(), 1), Val = cumsum(c(100, rnorm(200))))

    list(pf = pf, nav = ts_info, data = ts_data)

  })

  observe({
    if(input$fund != '') {
      output$tsplot <- renderPlotly({
        p <- ggplot(PFobj()$data, aes(x = Dat, y = Val, group = 1, text = paste("</br>Date: ", Dat, "</br>Value: ", Val))) +
          geom_line(colour = "red")
        ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
      })
    }
  })

  output$hover <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (!is.null(d)) {cat(d$x, d$y); b <<- d$x}
  })

})
```

[image: App]

Answer (score 0):

edit: after some research, it seems that the output is the pointer X-axis value of the graph position. Try `print(d)` inside your `hover` output. `d$x` and `d$y` are empty.

Comment: Does the `verbatimTextOutput("hover")` field output it correctly too?

Comment: haha, oh right. I just screenshotted it right away and didnt see the output. Yeah it's screwed. my bad